# Selenium C# web scraping - failed to resolve/parse html PageSource

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, anglesharp

I have made myself a simple .NET console app in C# to scrape a dynamic page for personal use using Selenium C#.

The selenium navigation works perfectly fine, but when I am about to resolve the resulting page source and retrieve a list of real estate addresses, it returns null.  And on top of that, it also gives warning and errors relating to chrome browser.

**Full code:**

```
public static void SeleniumExtract()
{
    // initial setup
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.knightfrank.co.uk/");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    // dropdown
    var dropdown1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cpMain_ucc1_ctl00_liResidentialFront"));
    dropdown1.Click();
    
    // enter search query
    var search = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cpMain_ucc1_ctl00_txtResidentialSearchBox"));
    search.Click();
    search.SendKeys("London");

    // select search suggection from dropdown menu
    wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ui-id-4")));
    var suggestion = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ui-id-4"));
    suggestion.Click();

    // submit search
    var submit = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='cpMain_ucc1_ctl00_pnlContentResidential']//a[@class='search-button']"));
    submit.Click();

    // get the data
    var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='grid-address']"));
    
    foreach(var item in elements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
    }

}
```

**Problem #1 - Selenium:**

Selenium does not return any result to console.  The xpath `//div[@class='grid-address']` is absolutely accurate, so no typo mistakes.  I don't know why it doesn't output the foreach items result to console, i.e. this part of the code doesn't work:

```
// get the data
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='grid-address']"));

foreach(var item in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
}
```

**Problem #2 - Html Agility pack:**

Alternatively, I have tried to use Html Agility Pack to parse the PageSource, it just returns empty null exception.

First, I return the page source from SeleniumExtract():

```
// export current pagesource
var currentPage = driver.PageSource;
return currentPage;
```

And then, I load the page source into Html Agility Pack to work with. It returns nothing!

```
public static void HapParse(string currentPage)
{
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.Load(currentPage);

    var address = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
        .SelectNodes("//div[@class='grid-address']")
        .ToList();

    foreach(var item in address)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
    }
    
}
```

**Problem #3 - AngleSharp:**

Tried to do the same with Angle Sharp, and still not working.

```
public static async void AngleSharpParse(string currentPage)
{
    var config = Configuration.Default;
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

    var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(currentPage));

    var elements = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.grid-address");

    foreach (var item in elements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.TextContent);
    }
}
```

**Problem #4 - Warning and error relating to Chrome browser:**

The console also returns the following errors everytime I execute the code:

```
[39536:28224:1103/183909.271:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[39536:28224:1103/183909.271:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[39536:28224:1103/183909.271:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[39536:39768:1103/183909.275:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:39:09.274] USB: usb_service_win.cc:389 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[39536:39768:1103/183909.280:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:39:09.280] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 
Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[39536:28224:1103/183909.291:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
[39536:39768:1103/183909.310:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:39:09.310] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 
Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

---

Please can someone tell me why this very simple code just doesn't return anyresult?

p.s.

I actually tried to code the exact same thing in Python using Selenium and Beautiful Soup and everything works perfectly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your Chrome version and what is your Selenum.WebDriver.ChromeDriver version ?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: @DejanJanjušević ChromeDriver Version 94.0.4606.61, and Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69. I will try to download the latest ChromeDriver and see if the warnings go away.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Nope. I've upgraded the ChromeDriver from version 94.0.4606.61 to version 95.0.4638.54, and the warnings and errors are still there.....

Comment: Then it's probably something wrong with the code. I will try to reproduce later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply needed to add a wait timer after Selenium submitted the search query, such as `Thread.Sleep(3000)`, to let the page to fully load before parsing the HTML.

Comment: It's not wise to do that, you never know how long you will have to wait for the result. Rather wait for `body > div.initial-load` to disappear. First wait for it to appear, to be sure that results are being processed, and then wait for it to be hidden. That will, in this case, ensure you have the results available.